# how to read checked/unchecked state of a checkbox from view in controller in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, checkbox

I am using MVC 3 with Razor, I have a number of check boxes that I am generating on my view.

Below is the code I am using

```
<input type="checkbox" value="@req" id="@inputCheckBoxId" name="@inputCheckBoxId"/
```

@req is a bool value I am setting using data from the database (as true/ false)

I normally read values from such fields using Request["nameOfTheControl"], but in this case whenever I see while debugging the value I get from Request is FALSE, each time.

Please share your views on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="@(req ? "checked" : "")" id="@inputCheckBoxId" name="@inputCheckBoxId"/>
```

you have to set `req` to checked attribute if `req` is true

Comment: I have no problem in setting the value, problem is when I read it ? Is my reading value method proper ?

Comment: if your variable req is false while rendering view and then when you checked the checkbox and submit form you get the req variable value. If you wanna get true value when chekckbox checked, then you should set value of <input> to "True" like this <input type="checkbox" value="True/>"

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue in your code but I suggest you use Firebug (Net tab) in Firefox to figure out the data that is getting posted to your Controller. You could determine the name of the parameter that is sent via the HTTP request for the checkbox value.

Hope it helps.

Kiran Banda